# Why does (g)awk reverse these lines of output?

Tags: awk, race-condition, gawk

So, I'm seeing this output and I'm a bit surprised:

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g" | cut -d, -f-4
a,b,c,d
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g" | cut -d, -f6-
f,g
echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g" | awk '{ print $0 | "cut -d, -f-4"; print $0 | "cut -d, -f6-"; }'
f,g
a,b,c,d
```

(As a side note, I realize this is a completely silly thing to do in `awk`, but it's the only command I've seen it happen for!).

As I understand it, this should pipe the record into the two commands -- in order.  But for some reason, the output appears reversed.  If I do this instead

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g" | awk '{ print $0 | "echo hello"; print $0 | "echo goodbye"; }'
hello
goodbye
```

then everything comes in the order I expected.  I'm thinking this must be some sort of race condition, but I'm surprised that `awk` doesn't wait for the subcommand in the pipe to finish.  Is this a known issue of using `awk` or something pecular to `gawk`? Is there any way to avoid such a pitfall?

**EDIT:**

I tried it using `mawk` too... same (reversed) result, and seems to happen consistently for both.

Comment: Testing this using `date`, I had output in both orders. `echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g" | awk '{ print $0 | "date \"+A%s.%N\""; print $0 | "date \"+B%s.%N\""; }'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to ensure that an external command is completed, you must [close](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html#Close-Files-And-Pipes) the command.

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g" | awk 'BEGIN {cmd1 = "cut -d, -f-4"; cmd2 = "cut -d, -f6-"} { print $0 | cmd1; close(cmd1); print $0 | cmd2; close(cmd2)}'
a,b,c,d
f,g
```

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised by this but it's clear that awk runs commands in parallel.  Try this:

```
# time echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g" | awk '{ print $0 | "sleep 2"; print $0 | "sleep 2"; }'

real    0m2.250s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.060s
```